# EXE_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0*4) in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When i use Quiclblox for(App To App Audio and Video Calling) and twilio for(App to Mobile Audio Calling) both in my application then i faced the problem, `EXE_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0*4)` in IOS(xcode).

But if i use only Quickblox in my application then it works fine,also when i only use twilio then it's also work fine in my app.

But problem comes when i use both third party liabraies(**QuickBlox and Twilio**) then it shows me:-  **`EXE_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0*4)`**
error: memory read failed for 0x0

I don't know about this please help me.
I use Zombie to solve this and try to work on instrument to solve this but didn't get anything.